# shiny application, radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

When i check the first choice"1 jeux de donnée" i analyze just one data (i do a linear regression) and i can choose the range of anlyzis thanks to a slider. But my problem is when i check the second choice " 2jeux de données" the slider of my first analysis disappear and i have only one slider(for the linear regression of my second data). So what i want is to see the two sliders when i choose the second choice in the radiobuttons.

```
sidebarPanel(
  wellPanel(
    radioButtons("number_of_data", "Combien de donnée voulez-vous comparer ?",
                 choices = c("1 jeu de donnée", "2 jeux de données"
                             ))),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.number_of_data == '1 jeu de donnée'",                                    
  wellPanel(
  fileInput("file1", "Choisir votre 1er fichier tabulé"), 
  checkboxInput("fit_weibull", label = "Ajuster une loi de Weibull", value = FALSE),
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = "input.fit_weibull == true",
              uiOutput("slider"))
            )
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.number_of_data == '2 jeux de données'", 
    wellPanel(
      fileInput("file2", "Choisir votre 2e fichier tabulé"), 
      checkboxInput("fit_weibull2", label = "Ajuster une loi de Weibull", value = FALSE),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.fit_weibull2 == true",
        uiOutput("slider2"))  
      )
  ),

  img(src="renault-fluence-ze-20.jpg", height = 200, width = 350))
```

Comment: Why do you use a `conditionalPanel` for the 1st file if this panel must always be displayed regardless of the button checked ?

Comment: Thank you very much you are right !
But if i had a third file how can i solve the problem ?